# Where are Eclipse remote debugging packages?

Tags: eclipse, remote-debugging

I would like to remotely debug a C++ application. I use Eclipse CDT Helios and Mac OS X as host. I read this guide:

http://www.embedded-linux.co.uk/tutorial/eclipse-rse

But for me it is not clear:

1) which are the equivalent eclipse remote packages to install
2) which eclipse packages source should I specifiy. I tried to find in the default ones but nothing

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Helios update repository the components are now under the *Mobile and Device Development* Category named *Remote System Explorer End User Runtime* and *Remote System Explorer User Actions*. Also useful is the *C/C++ Remote Debugger*.